# Google sheets returning correct value from json data

Tags: google-sheets, json

Example sheet to clarify my problem:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e04XmYkirDJCucCv5Z1czCtg2OQkJfWyThjhF3uz8FQ/edit?usp=sharing

I am fetching json data from a server, however on some fetches there is a column of data missing or added extra data, which doesn't allow me to just easily select the column of data that I would like to work further on.

**Sample**

[image: sample data]

In the example above, I would like to search each row of json data for historic and current value and have it separate from the json data, so that I can easily reference it for further use in the spreadsheet. Basically, how can I search each row for a key term(s) and return that associated value in a separate part of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. While a link to an external resource might be helpful, questions should be self contained, so please add more details and clarify what you are actually asking, (are you looking for help with a Google Sheets built-in feature or with using Google Apps Script?)

Comment: Your sample spreadsheet also does not contain *realistic* data or the *hand-entered results* you want a formula to produce. For instance, I see Row 2 contains "current value #1" in cells E2 and I2; but what does that look like in real life. It is certain that the actual values won't be the string "current value #1"; it is uncertain, however, what that data might really look like. Will it follow some predictable pattern by which it can be identified? Will the same exact value show up multiple times in a row as you have show? Short version: change your sample data to be *realistic*.

Answer (score 2):

Enter this formula in cell I1:

`={query({flatten(A1:G)},"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'current'"),query({flatten(A1:G)},"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'historic'")}`

---

**Result**
[image: Output]

---

**Logic**

- `flatten(A1:G)` - takes the entire data source and reduces it to a single column of data
- `"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'current'"` - returns the values containing the word "current"
- `"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'historic'"`- returns the values containing the word "historic"
- `{query(),query()}` - creates an array; use of the "comma" arranges the results side-by side.